# Have to save text height in d using d3 library

Tags: javascript, d3.js, getboundingclientrect

I am trying to save text height value in d (so I can draw around appropriate size rectangle), but it's not defined in tick function or any where else.

```
d.height
```

should hold values. (but it doesn't)

So I have tick function (part of it):

```
  function tick() {
    z.attr('d', function(d) {
    alert (d.height); //not defined
var sourceX = d.source.x + textWidth/2 + 10,
    sourceY = d.source.y + d.height/2 + 10,
    targetX = d.target.x + textWidth/2 + 10,
    targetY = d.target.y + d.height/2 + 10;      

return 'M' + sourceX + ',' + sourceY + 'L' + targetX + ',' + targetY;
});

shape.attr('transform', function(d) {
middle_rect.attr("height", d.height/2 + 20);        
side_rect.attr("height", d.height/2 + 20);   
return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';        
});
```

And here how I'm trying to save values (bottom of code)

```
     shape = shape.data(nodes);
// add new nodes
 var g = shape.enter().append('svg:g').attr('class', function(d) { return d.type +'        node'; });

   middle_rect = svg.selectAll(".middle")
   .append("svg:rect")
   .attr("rx", "10")
   .attr("ry", "10")
   .style("stroke", "rgb(47,136,214)")
   .style("fill", "url(#middle_gradient)");


  side_rect = svg.selectAll(".side")
   .append("svg:rect")
   .attr("rx", "10")
   .attr("ry", "10")
   .style("stroke", "rgb(47,136,214)")
   .style("fill", "url(#side_gradient)");



  txt = g.append('svg:text')
   .attr('class',function (d){return 'bigest ' + d.id ;}  )
   .attr('y', ".5em")
   .attr("dy", "1em")
   .style("fill", "black")
   .each (function (d) {
    d.height =  this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    // alert (d.height); //here I have this value
});
```

Can I make it global? Or have to save these values?

Comment: What are you trying to assign to the txt variable? Where are you wanting the height to be accessible from? What would you want to happen should there be multiple entries traversed by the .each function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to attach a height field to the Node itself, which is considered a bad practice in general.

Why not create a data structure to store all these values, or possibly even add the height to your dataset.

Another approach could be creating a data-height attribute on the text node.

http://jsfiddle.net/heavyhorse/893jT/

```
svg.selectAll('text.data-label').each(function(d, i){
    var height = this.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    var width = this.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    console.log(i+': ('+width+','+height+')');

    // create custom data-attr:
    this.setAttribute('data-width', width);
    this.setAttribute('data-height', height);
    console.log(this);

    // attach to dataset:
    dataset[i].width = width;
    dataset[i].height = height;
});
```